# jQuery combine statements?

Tags: jquery

How can I simplify these statements, instead of having to count all the way upt to 34 and having 34 separate statements…..

```
$('a#timeline-2010-lnk1').click(function() {
    $('#timeline-2010-1').show();
    return false;
  }); 

$('a#timeline-2010-lnk2').click(function() {
    $('#timeline-2010-2').show();
    return false;
  });

$('a#timeline-2010-lnk3').click(function() {
    $('#timeline-2010-3').show();
    return false;
  });

$('a#timeline-2010-lnk4').click(function() {
    $('#timeline-2010-4').show();
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: can you please provide simplified HTML of a timeline-2010-lnk1 and timeline-2010-1 including the relation between this two elements and any parent nodes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$("a[id^=timeline-2010-lnk]").live("click", function () {
    var num = this.id.split(/-(?:lnk)?/).pop();
    $('#timeline-2010-'+num).show();
    return false;
});
```

More efficient because it uses *[delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)/[live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)*. Instead of attaching many click handlers, a single handler is placed on the common ancestor node, which click events will bubble up to.

As @rochal [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637460/jquery-combine-statements/3637512#3637512), even more appropriate might be to use a single class name for all the elements and taking advantage of the relationship between the two elements (via parent/etc).  However, if you can, you should still consider using *live()* or *delegate()* for the handler.

Comment: nice answer!   is using an id^= selector more efficient then a class selector?

Comment: @Patricia: not much.  If you can go with classes, it's probably a better idea - but *live()* is still more efficient than many *click()* handlers (which was kind of the point of my answer).

Answer (score 4):

Add a common className to every element:

```
<a href="#" id="timeline-2010-lnk1" class="clicker">Text 1</a>
<a href="#" id="timeline-2010-lnk2" class="clicker">Text 2</a>
<a href="#" id="timeline-2010-lnk3" class="clicker">Text 3</a>
<a href="#" id="timeline-2010-lnk4" class="clicker">Text 4</a>
<a href="#" id="timeline-2010-lnk5" class="clicker">Text 5</a>
...
```

Then, you could simplify your HTML, and get rid of  IDs all together:

```
<a href="#" class="clicker">Text 1</a>
<a href="#" class="clicker">Text 2</a>
<a href="#" class="clicker">Text 3</a>
<a href="#" class="clicker">Text 4</a>
<a href="#" class="clicker">Text 5</a>
...
```

Then, all you have to do is:

```
$('.clicker').click(function() {
    $(this). /* parent? sibling? I'd have to see your code */ .show();
    return false;
});
```

Node regarding my comment in the code:

I assume that `#timeline-2010-[X]` is some sort of div you want to show, so instead of using IDs again, apply a class and use `.siblings()` or `.find()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop like `Luca` suggested earlier (deleted). But you have to create a helper "self-invoking function" in order to keep things right:

```
for(var i=1; i<=34; i++) {
    (function(index){
        $('a#timeline-2010-lnk'+index).click(function() {
           $('#timeline-2010-'+index).show();
           return false;
        });
    })(i);
}​
```

Why is that? Javascript only has `function scope` and not a `block scope` like in most other C-like languages. So `i` is not bound to the scope of the `for-loop` THEREFORE the `closure functions` you're creating as event handler to `click` will all reference to the same `i`.

By creating a new function which invokes itself at runtime, you can workaround this issue.

Comment: Yeah always forget about this.. +1

Comment: Your closing `)` for the closure is mis-placed. I did an edit, but it was overwritten by your latest edit. I assume it was just an oversight. :o)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're using jQuery, try something like this:

```
$('a[id^=timeline-2010-lnk]').click(function() {
    var id = '#' + this.id.replace(/lnk/, '');
    $(id).show();
    return false;
});
```

This will grab all links whose id attribute starts with "timeline-2010-lnk" and attach a click event.  You get the corresponding id by simply removing the "lnk" part from the link's id.

Here's a doc for the "attribute starts with" selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Additionally, here's a simple demo showing this method in action: http://jsfiddle.net/eL3Yw/

Answer (score 0):

Use a startswith attribute selector with $.each

```
$('a[id^=timeline-2010-lnk]').each(function () {
    var idx = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+$/);

    if (idx !== null) {
        $(this).click(function () {
            $('#timeline-2010-' + idx[0]).show();
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```